# Why does this review of Star Trek IV include an image of Link from Legend of Zelda?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, the-legend-of-zelda

I was watching a recent review of Star Trek IV and noticed a very brief flash of this image during the review:

[image]

[Link to video at the time where this occurs](https://youtu.be/iv5CBciH8G0?t=635).

Thanks to Google image search I found out that the image is the character Link, from The Legend of Zelda game, holding the "Triforce".

What if any is the connection with the movie or with Star Trek? I'm not very familiar with Zelda and know very little about it.

Notes:

- The image pops up during a discussion of how the film was screened in the USSR
- It's shown at the moment the narrator says the word "biggest"
- That's Spock in the background, the placement seems intentional (?)

I think Zelda came out in the 80s, maybe around the time of this movie.

Comment: With regards to the dates, _Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home_ was 1986, that looks like the Link from _The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past_, which was 1991.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's a simple visual pun, drawing attention to the fact that the design on the front of Spock's robe:

[image: A cropped image of Spock wearing a white robe. Visible on the chest is a design consisting of 4 equilateral triangles outlined in gray, with the top one partially hidden by a robe's folded hood.]

bears a resemblance to the [Triforce](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Triforce):

[image: A golden object consisting of three equilateral triangles emblazoned with symbols, joined at the corners, with a fourth triangle formed by the negative space between them]

an iconic symbol of the Legend of Zelda franchise.

There's no deeper connection between Star Trek and the Legend of Zelda, or between Spock and Link. It just so happens that both feature triangles.

Comment: There are further connections: they both have pointy ears and very low empathy (Spock tries to live without emotion on purpose, and Link breaks and enters into other people's houses to break stuff for kicks).

Comment: @MarvelBoy Not for kicks. He's looking for Rupees, the Zelda currency. Which would probably make it even worse because it makes him a thief.

Comment: @Nzall Not sure that thievery "breaking stuff to find money (to buy equipment to defeat a villain)" is in fact worse than psychopathy "breaking stuff because it's fun."

Comment: @Timbo But he has no reason to believe there's money in them until he breaks them for fun, so...

Comment: I totally missed the similar imagery, maybe because Spock's hood is covering a big part of it!

Comment: Rupees, eh? So Zelda is in India?